# Preventing subtraction to appearing in formula bar (Excel 2010, VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, formula, subtraction

Seeking help!
Hi,
I am almost done on a project and there's a part I don't understand
I have a `+` and a `-` button to add amounts from it's left cell to a total cell on the right (reads 54 in the example) (shown in the link down below) 
Also, the amount of times the `+` is pressed is also calculated on the far most cell (2 for this example)

From the following code I made:

```
Range("L8").FormulaLocal = "=" & Replace(Range("L8").FormulaLocal, "=", "") & "+" & Range("G8")
```

The problem is that with the same code, using subtraction, I don't want to see it in the formula bar as it ends up as:
`=29+29+29-29-29+29...` (2nd image)

I only want to keep the positives. Is there something in the above mentioned code that I can change that will not show the subtraction though and not erase the whole formula that is there already

Thanks!

Part of my excel sheet for better understanding:

[image]

What I don't want to see in my formula bar:

[image]

Comment: You are editing a formula. The formula will determine what result shows in the cell. If you don't want to see the whole formula in the formula editor, do the calculation in VBA and only write the result to the cell. You can NOT remove parts of a formula and expect the result to be something other than what the formula would return.

Comment: All you could do is add a line-break at some point, which would hide the part of the formula to the right of that, since most people only have the formula bar high enough to display the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, shouldn't the value in your screenshot be 58, not 54?

Next, does the cell really need to contain a formula? As @teylyn mentioned, just do the calculation in VBA and set the cell's value.  E.g. for the `+` button:

```
Range("L8").Value = Range("L8").Value + Range("G8").Value
```

Finally, if you really need to keep the formula, and you know that the value in cell `G8` (the value being added or subtracted) never changes between clicks of the `+` and `-` buttons, you could first increment the counter (which I assume is cell `M8`), and then use its value to build the formula.

That might look something like the following, although you'd want to add some error trapping. Also, if you can ensure the counter will never be negative, you could eliminate the `ElseIf` portion:

```
Public Sub MinusButton_Click()
    Range("M8").Value = Range("M8").Value - 1
    Range("L8").FormulaLocal = GetCellFormula
End Sub

Public Sub PlusButton_Click()
    Range("M8").Value = Range("M8").Value + 1
    Range("L8").FormulaLocal = GetCellFormula
End Sub

Private Function GetCellFormula()
    Dim strFormula As String
    Dim intNum As Integer

    strFormula = "="

    If Range("M8").Value > 0 Then
      For intNum = 1 To Range("M8").Value
        strFormula = strFormula & Range("G8").Value & "+"
      Next intNum
    ElseIf Range("M8").Value < 0 Then
      For intNum = Range("M8").Value To 1 Step -1
        strFormula = strFormula & Range("G8").Value & "-"
      Next intNum
    End If

    strFormula = Left(strFormula, Len(strFormula) - 1) 'strip trailing symbol

    GetCellFormula = strFormula
End Function
```

Otherwise, if the value in cell `G8` may change, your only option may be to do some (potentially) complicated parsing of the existing formula. If that's the case, please give it a try first, and post a new SO Question if you have any issues.

Comment: MJH, that almost did it! Numbers are adding and subtracting as expected and negatives are not shown anymore in the formula bar as I asked.However, as you mentioned, value in cell G8 is never the same (in fact, I use that cell to add skid count and my example was not the best to use, I agree on that). What is the complicated parsing of the formula you<re talking about?

Comment: That would be some new logic you would need to write, which would parse the existing formula, and modify it according to your requirements. As an example, let's say cell `G8` has a value of `42`, and the user clicked the `+` button. Depending on the requirements, your logic may have to take into account such factors as: 1. Cell `L8` currently has no formula; 2. Cell `L8` has a formula but it contains a value of `420`, which you don't want to match; 3. Does the value appear at the start of the formula (need to match `=42`), or later on in the formula (need to match `+42`); etc.